# How to add permission for "Permit drawing over the other apps" by default without user prompt while installing the Android app for first time?

Tags: android, permissions, runtime

[image]   I have installed Facebook's Messenger app from Google play store and by default it checked with "Permit drawing over the other apps" permission without user interaction. Can I add same in my Android app without user operations or any other suggestion for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this permission :

```
android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
```

Comment: yes, still it disable by default. Please check screenshot above